# Using a globally reusable workflow

Tags: workflow, deployment, sharepoint-designer

I have created a globally reusable workflow in Sharepiont Designer. I was able to save it as a .wsp. I would like to deploy and use this workflow to a different site collection. After succesfully deploying the solution, and after I activate it in Manage Site Features, I can't find the workflow under System Settings > Workflow. I also can't find it when I try to Add a Workflow to a List Library.

I originally created a list workflow for a specific list library and it worked perfectly. Now I am having trouble duplicating that in the form of a globally reusable workflow.

Is there something I am missing in the deploying and activating of a globally reusable workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After activating your feature, you still need to publish the workflow to your new site in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: The problem I have with that is that I will not have access to the server or site collection. Ideally, I want to create a wsp file or xsn template that the end user can deploy and activate on their own with ease. Do you have any suggestions for doing this? Perhaps a way to do it in the code behind of the wsp file or some sort of auto publish option?

Comment: You could import your wsp in Visual Studio. Then deploy the Visual Studio workflow, which does not need to be published.

Comment: @Laurie I am having the exact same issue, but I dont have sharepoint designer on the production environment, so the only way is importing the workflow in visual studio? is this limitation documented somewhere?